# Does returning a byte[] directly from a Spring Controller create a memory leak?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have this method in a Spring Controller and I would like to be sure not to create a memory leak. Does it, or does it not?

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/document/{id}/{filename:.*}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public byte[] getDownloadEclaimsDocument(@PathVariable("id") final String id, @PathVariable("filename") final String fileName, final HttpServletResponse response) {
    final DmsFile dmsFile = dmsService.getByFileSystemId(id);
    response.setContentType(dmsFile.getContentType());
    // This call gets a byte[] from a backend service
    return dmsService.getFileAsByteArray(dmsFile);
}
```

Comment: Why would you suspect that it does? What is the cause for concern specifically about byte arrays rather than anything else?

Comment: I used to return a FileSystemResource which needs a File. I wanted to avoid that not to create a (temporary) File on every request. Since I made that change I am having "OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded" frequently.

Comment: So you should include that information within the question. I doubt that it's a matter of returning a byte array that is the problem - but it could be a problem with `dmsService` etc.

Comment: dmsService remained unchanged for a while. I just wondered what the JVM does with the byte[] once it served it to the browser...

Comment: Once the browser has received all the data, it should be eligible for garbage collection, unless something else (e.g. `dmsService`) has retained a reference to it. At this stage it's probably worth breaking out a profiler.

Comment: A 1 GB file doesn't occupy 1GB memory, a byte array that size does. I'm confused by your statement _"I wanted to avoid that not to create a (temporary) File on every request"_ . Your current solution seems to read an existing file. Why don't you serve that directly? What is the temporary file that you are talking about?

Comment: @zeroflagL my dmsService does not create a temporary or intermediate java.io.File. It merely returns a byte[]. Before I used to create a temporary File, and pass it to FileSystemResource.

Comment: @zeroflagL an Object holding only metadata about files.

Comment: So there is a file and the question remains: Why don't / can't you serve that directly?

Comment: @zeroflagL There is no File which I can access directly. There is a File on a remote host, which I can get as byte[] via a REST-api. Then I can either create a temporary java.io.File from that byte[], and serve it as FileSystemResoure. I don't want that because I do not want to take care of cleaning up those temporary files. It's much more straightforward to serve the byte[] directly. The only question was/is if the byte[] is GC'ed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe better use `org.springframework.core.io.Resource`?

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/document/{id}/{filename:.*}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Resource getDownloadEclaimsDocument(@PathVariable("id") final String id, 
        @PathVariable("filename") final String fileName, 
        final HttpServletResponse response,) {
    final DmsFile dmsFile = dmsService.getByFileSystemId(id);
    byte[] data = dmsService.getFileAsByteArray(dmsFile);

    response.setContentType(dmsFile.getContentType());
    response.setContentLength(data.length);
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", 
                       "attachment; filename=\"" +
                       MimeUtility.encodeWord(dsmFile.getName(), "utf-8", "Q") + "\"");

    // This call gets a byte[] from a backend service
    return new ByteArrayResource(data);
}
```